# Laravel Snappy error en windows

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Acabo de implementar laravel snappy en windows pero no me funciona, he seguido los siguiente pasos.

```
composer require wemersonjanuario/wkhtmltopdf-windows "0.12.2.3"

composer require barryvdh/laravel-snappy
```

En config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
        Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider::class,
    ],

'aliases' => [
        'PDF' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyPdf::class,
        'SnappyImage' => Barryvdh\Snappy\Facades\SnappyImage::class,
    ]

php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Snappy\ServiceProvider"
```

En config/snappy.php

```
return [
    'pdf' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => base_path('vendor\wemersonjanuario\wkhtmltopdf-windows\bin\64bit\wkhtmltopdf'),
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env' => array(),
    ),
    'image' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'binary' => 'vendor\wemersonjanuario\wkhtmltopdf-windows\bin\64bit\wkhtmltoimage',
        'timeout' => false,
        'options' => array(),
        'env' => array(),
    ),
];
```

Y obtengo el error

> Declaration of
> Barryvdh\Snappy\IlluminateSnappyPdf::getFileContents($filename) must
> be compatible with
> Knp\Snappy\AbstractGenerator::getFileContents(string $filename):
> string

Ya he limpiado el cache, tambien tengo instalado el wkhtmltopdf en windows y he reemplazado con la ubicación de archivos de programa en C.